# Why HTTP sniffers aren't able to capture PHP generated HTTP traffic?

Tags: php, http, packet-sniffer

I can't get why HTTP Analyzer (I prefer this one because it is capable of decoding SSL encoded data transfered through HTTPS) isn't able to capture PHP generated HTTP traffic. It capture HTTP traffic of every application except PHP (httpd.exe indeed). It even capture mysql-client's traffic tunneled through HTTP proxy but can't capture plain PHP's HTTP traffic. I tried various HTTP sniffers, but result is always the same. I mean exactly HTTP sniffers, not TCP ones.

Any idea? Is it possible that PHP issues HTTP request in some other way than others do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like some issue about not sniffing from the same source.

1. Different client application? Maybe you are using a client that HTTP analyzer is not connected to/cannot sniff.
2. Different interface? Maybe you are accessing some service via LAN address (`192.168.*`) and some other via localhost (`127.0.0.1`)

Comment: Seconds seems to be true. I checked whether HA got traffic of command line PHP interpreter and it got it ! So problem seems to be in Apache which runs as localhost. It's a pity I can't choose which interface to use in HA

Comment: Is your PHP curling to your local apache ? if so then make sure that apache listen to an external interface (LAN is OK) and then change your curl script to send request to this IP rather than 127.0.0.1

Comment: No, I use local apache to test script curling to internet host, so it sends requests to internet IP. I changed settings of local apache so now it runs on LAN IP rather then 127.0.0.1. But HA still doesn't capture apache's traffic. So problem seems to be apache+HA , not local interface

Comment: Weird. Is there several lan interfaces ? please upload your ipconfig/ifconfig

Comment: Yes, there is one additional virtual LAN interface for virtual machine but apache is clearly binded to my real LAN interface and apache's environment var `SERVER_ADDR` returns my LAN IP